# Computing a probability of 5 or more same values when rolling 21 fair dice 12 sides each

Tags: probability

The way I'd like to approach the problem is to calculate separate probabilities (P(1), P(2), P(3), P(4)) and then calculate P(>=5) = 1 - (P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + P(4)) where:

- P(1) is the probability of having exactly one side of the dice represented and 20 others different. For example: 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 (1 is repeated exactly once)
- P(2) is the probability of having one side of the dice represented exactly 2 times and 19 others different. For example: 5 1 2 3 4 2 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 (5 is repeated 2 times)
- P(3) is the probability of having one side of the dice represented exactly 3 times and 18 others different. For example: 6 6 1 6 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 (6 is repeated 3 times)
- P(4) is the probability of having one side of the dice represented exactly 4 times and 17 others different. For example: 7 1 2 7 3 4 7 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 1 2 3 4 5 6 (7 is repeated 4 times)

My issue is that I having trouble calculating the number of combinations for each example yet calculating the overall number of combinations is trivial (${12^{21}}$).
What I came up with so far is as follows:

- P(1) = $\binom{21}{1}⋅12⋅{11^{20}}$
- P(2) = $\binom{21}{2}⋅{12^2}⋅{11^{19}}$
- P(3) = $\binom{21}{3}⋅{12^3}⋅{11^{18}}$
- P(4) = $\binom{21}{4}⋅{12^4}⋅{11^{17}}$

I know duplicates aren't ruled out in these formulas but I am not sure I can come up with calculating the number of these duplicates.
To illustrate the point, suppose we have the following combination: 1 5 6 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9.
We can see that it matches the case of P(1) for 1, 5, 6, 7 and 9 which means that combination could have been repeated at least 4 times, however, the number of repetitions varies depending on the combination.
The question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487093/discrete-math-probability-function-rolling-12-sided-die), however, I can't properly eliminate duplicates.
Hints and points would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simulation suggests a probability of approximately $0.298$, and a direct count confirms it to be $0.2981005847\dots$

Comment: Yep, I came across approximately the same numbers using Monte-Carlo simulation but my mind is stuck on the analytical way of computing that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the generating functions the probability in question reads:

$$
1-\frac{21![x^{21}]\left(1+\frac x{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^{12}}{12^{21}},\tag1
$$
where the operator $[x^{n}]$ extracts the coefficient at $x^n$ in the subsequent expression.

---

UPDATE:

To understand what is going on in (1) substitute:
$$
\left(1+\frac x{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^{12}\to\prod_{i=1}^{12}\left(1+\frac {x_i}{1!}+\frac{x_i^2}{2!}+\frac{x_i^3}{3!}+\frac{x_i^4}{4!}\right)
$$
After expanding the last expression you will obtain:
$$
\sum_{0\le k_1,\dots, k_{12}\le4}\prod_{i=1}^{12}\frac{x_i^{k_i}}{k_i!}
=\sum_{K=0}^{48}\frac1{K!}\sum_{0\le k_1,\dots, k_{12}\le4}^{\sum k_i=K}K!\prod_{i=1}^{12}\frac{x_i^{k_i}}{k_i!}.
$$

Now observe that the multinomial coefficient $\frac{K!}{\prod_{i=1}^{12}k_i!}$ is exactly the number of ways to permute $K$ objects with the number of objects of type $i$ being $k_i$. If you now set $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{12}=x$ all the coefficients appear to be at $x^K$ and summing them you end up with the coefficient at $x^K$ in
$$K!\left(1+\frac x{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}\right)^{12}.\tag2
$$

If you do not have an appropriate computer program for extracting the coefficient, you can either expand the expresson (2) by hand (doing this you may drop all intermediate terms with power of $x$ greater than 21) or resort to the method proposed in the other answer.

Comment: Best way (+1) if OP knows.

Comment: @user, could you, please, elaborate in more detail on the steps leading to the final formula?

Comment: And the second question (pardon if it's silly) is one can actually calculate the actual value (a real number) using that formula?

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko I have updated the answer.

Comment: @user, thank you. A couple of questions if I may:
* is it correct to say that 1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4 are the probabilities of each side of dice to accept values of 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively, hence 0.2?
* if K is [x^21], then where did 21! came from?

Comment: $x_i^k$ stays for the event "the side $i$ has shown up $k$ times in $K$ trials. In your case $K=21$.

Comment: Could you, please, give a hint on how to calculate one of the $x_i^k$ terms (for example, $x_i^3$)?

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko You should not calculate $x^k $. You should calculate the coefficient at $x^k $. For example the coefficient at $x^2$ in $(1+x)^4$ is equal to $6$.

Comment: I see. I used [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28sum+x%5En%2Fn%21%2C+n%3D0+to+4%29+%5E+12) Wolfram Alpha input to obtain the $[x^{21}]$ coefficient which is equal to $\frac{629076349}{995328}$. Could you, please, explain why we use the Taylor series of $e^{x}$ to express each side of a die instead of a regular polynomial (e.g. $1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3} + x^{4}$)? Apologies in advance if I miss something obvious.

Comment: @ViacheslavMoskalenko I have tried to explain this in the "update". Briefly the regular polynomial is used when the permutations do not matter. In your problem they matter.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am describing  how to compute the number of ways you can have $\le4$ repetitions w/o using inclusion-exclusion, but have to say it'll be laborious.

I arrange the configurations to be excluded in descending order, eg

$4-4-4-4-4-1-0-0-0-0-0-0$

$4-4-4-4-3-2-0-0-0-0-0-0$

---

$4-4-4-4-2-1-1-0-0-0-0-0\;\;$ etc down to

$2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1$

for each such configuration, find the product of two multinomial coefficients, eg for the third one in the line,

$\dbinom{21}{4,4,4,4,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}\dbinom{12}{4,1,2,5}$

Add up the figures to obtain ways to be *excluded* = say, $N$,

then $Pr = 1 - \frac{N}{12^{21}}$

Comment: @Daniel Mathias : Thanks, I understand, have revised

Comment: A direct count confirmed my earlier simulation result of  $Pr\approx 0.298$ with a result $Pr\approx 0.2981005847$ Your description provides for a shorter algorithm than I used.

Comment: ... down to $2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1$

Comment: @Daniel Mathias: Yes, of course !